# Load iPython/Jupyter Notebook from URL

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I am missing something basic, I'm sure. If I have a jupyter notebook at a url like this https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pyconca/blob/master/jupyter_magic.ipynb, how can I view it as an interactive notebook that I can then edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load it from a few places online and of course offline.  The easiest way to get this loaded offline is downloading Python + Jupyter and that can be found in one place.  Download and install Anaconda (2.7 or 3.4) from http://continuum.io/downloads and depending on your OS,

- If you run **mac or linux** restart a terminal and run "ipython notebook" which will open a browser to navigate you to the right location (your downloads folder) to find the .ipynb file
- if you run **Windows** there is an icon in the applications menu to start "Ipython notebook"  which will open a browser to navigate you to the right location (your downloads folder) to find the .ipynb file

Online there is a site called http://Wakari.io/ (requires an account) from which you can share the result with others.